# How to write this in Fortran?

Tags: matlab, syntax, fortran

I have the following MATLAB code which does the following.

Suppose I have 3 investments of 10 units. Matrix `exits` has a value of 1 if the investment is exited. Matrix `pos` tells me the return of each of the three investments. Then the last line of the code computes the total money earned on exited investments.

I am trying to write a similar lines of code in Fortran. Also below my Fortran attempt.

```
clear all

X = 10;
ret(1,1) = -0.05;
ret(2,1) = 0.15;

exits = [1 0 1];
pos = [1 1 2];
ret1 = (pos == 1) .* ret(1,1) + (pos == 2) .* ret(2,1);

inv = sum(X * ones(1,3) .* (exits) .* exp(ret1));
```

My Fortran code:

```
PROGRAM Matlab_replication
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER, DIMENSION(1,1) :: X = 10
REAL, DIMENSION(2,1) :: ret
INTEGER, DIMENSION(1,3) :: exits
INTEGER, DIMENSION(1,3) :: pos
REAL, DIMENSION(1,3) :: ret1
REAL, DIMENSION(1,3) :: ret2
REAL, DIMENSION(1,3) :: ones = 1.0
REAL, DIMENSION(1,3) :: X1
REAL :: inv

ret(1,1) = -0.05
ret(2,1) = 0.15

exits(1,1) = 1
exits(1,2) = 0
exits(1,3) = 1

pos(1,1) = 1
pos(1,2) = 1
pos(1,3) = 2

X1(1,:) = X(1,1) * ones(1,:)

ret1 = (pos == 1) * ret(1,1) + (pos == 2) * ret(2,1)
ret2(1,:) = exp(ret1(1,:))

inv = sum(X1(1,:) * exits(1,:)* ret2(1,:))



end program
```

Somehow the line  `ret1 = (pos == 1) * ret(1,1) + (pos == 2) * ret(2,1)` is not delivering what I am looking for. Also I had to create two additional variables versus the MATLAB code `X1` and `ret2`. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: What is your output? What does it do if it does not deliver what you are looking for? Consider more descriptive title.

Comment: I am not sure. The problem seems to be on the logical indexing of ret1. I made a few corrections on the fortran code, to make it exactly consistent with the matlab. But the output is not being the same.

Comment: So show the output, that's what I am asking for!

Comment: Hi Vladimir, not sure I understand exactly what you are looking for. 
What I expect is the Fortran code to make produce the exact same output as the Matlab code. On the example above the output variable is "inv" which on the matlab code is yielding:   inv = 21.1306;
The fortran code on the other hand is yielding inv = 19.11

Comment: Yes, I was looking for this. As HighPerformanceMark commented, I was also surprised it compiles at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pos == 1` in Matlab returns an array consisting of 1 and 0, while it returns an array consisting of `.true.` and `.false.` in Fortran (as suggested by @HighPerformanceMark). So, you need to take care of this difference somehow. There are various ways for this, and one such example is like this:

```
real :: ret( 2 ), vtmp( 3 ), inv, x
integer :: exits( 3 ), pos( 3 )

x = 10.0
ret = [ -0.05, 0.15 ]

exits = [ 1, 0, 1 ]
pos   = [ 1, 1, 2 ]

vtmp = abs([ integer:: pos == 1 ]) * ret( 1 ) + abs([ integer:: pos == 2 ]) * ret( 2 )

inv = sum( x * exits * exp( vtmp ) )
```

where I have assumed gfortran or Intel fortran and changed all 2-D arrays in the original code to 1-D arrays for simplicity.

---

For other compilers, the above code may be syntactically not allowed; in that case it may be useful to define some utility functions like

```
module filter_mod
    implicit none
    interface filter
        module procedure filter1D, filter2D
    end interface
contains
    function filter1D( mask ) result( ints )
        logical :: mask(:)
        integer :: ints( size( mask ) )
        ints = 0 ; where( mask ) ints = 1
    end function

    function filter2D( mask ) result( ints )
        logical :: mask(:,:)
        integer :: ints( size( mask, 1 ), size( mask, 2 ) )
        ints = 0 ; where( mask ) ints = 1
    end function
end module
```

and modify the original code as

```
PROGRAM Matlab_replication
use filter_mod
IMPLICIT NONE
...
ret1 = filter( pos == 1 ) * ret(1,1) + filter( pos == 2 ) * ret(2,1)
inv = sum( X(1,1) * exits * exp( ret1 ) )
```

which hopefully makes the translation from Matlab straight-forward.

---

EDIT: Actually, use of [`merge()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MERGE.html) function seems to be the simplest solution (thanks to @francescalus). With this function the first and second codes can be rewritten as

```
vtmp = merge( ret(1), 0.0, pos == 1 ) + merge( ret(2), 0.0, pos == 2 )
```

and

```
ret1 = merge( ret(1,1), 0.0, pos == 1 ) + merge( ret(2,1), 0.0, pos == 2 )
```

Because `merge()` returns an array with the same shape as `pos`, it is very straight-forward to use even for multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: The reason for attaching `abs()` is that gfortran gives `1` for `.true.` elements, while Intel fortran gives `-1` for them (hmm...). Because of this, if I omit `abs()`, ifort gives inv = 19.11979 instead of 21.13064.

Comment: There is also `merge(ret(1),0,pos==1)` to avoid the abomination of `abs([ integer:: pos == 1 ]) * ret(1)`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know this merge() function... I will check the usage later. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This may be an extended comment rather than an answer ...

The expression

```
(pos == 1) * ret(1,1) + (pos == 2) * ret(2,1)
```

mixes types in a way unacceptable to Fortran.  The first term, `(pos == 1)` is of type `logical` and evaluates to either `.true.` or `.false.`.  That is not something that can then be multiplied by a number, or by anything else for that matter.

Actually, matters are slightly worse than I first realised, since `pos` is an array.  Do you expect an array of results, or for a single result from that term ?

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you'll need to transform `(pos == 1)` to a number somehow if you want to multiply it.  It is fairly easy to write a Fortran function to return `1` (or whatever you want) for a `.true.` input, and another number for a `.false.` input.

Finally I'm surprised that your Fortran code is returning anything at all as you assert in your comment.  I'm surprised that it compiles.

Comment: If he's using GCC, it's probably [implicitly converting](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.3/gfortran/Implicitly-interconvert-LOGICAL-and-INTEGER.html) the type to an integer, and thus could compile the code. There should be a warning during compilation though...

Comment: Yes, now that I've had a chance to compile the code myself my installation of gfortran raises a warning, not an error.